# Finding $v_n$ such that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{w_n}{v_n} = 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that ($u_n$)$_n$ is a real sequence that is convergent to $L$. Cesaro’s lemma states that $(u_n)_n$ defined by

$u_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum{^n_{k=1}} u_k $

is convergent to $L$.
Using this Lemma, find an equivalent sequence $(v_n)_n$ of the sequence
$(w_n)_n$, defined by $w_n = 1+2^{1/2}+3^{1/3}+· · · n^{1/n}$
 That is find $(v_n)_n$, such that $w_n/v_n →_{n→∞} = 1$

Sort of confused by what it means to find an equivalent sequence. Question just seems kind of random. Any help? I mean doesn't $w_n$ diverge?

would $v_n = n$?

Comment: $u_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum{^n_{k=1}} u_k$ is a circular definition.

Comment: I don't know what they mean by "equivalent" but you are right, if you let $v_n:=n$ then $w_n/v_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ since the sequence $\{n^{1/n}\}$ converges to $1.$